# How to see the data points of most similar cluster(s) to another cluster in k-means clustering?

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-science, k-means

I'm having a dataset which consists of 2500+ houses information like price, sqft area, etc. I wanted to group similar houses on the basis of the house's location, price, number of bedrooms, and bathrooms. So taking these 4 as the input parameters, I applied k-means clustering and for determining the number of clusters (i.e. the value of k) I used the Silhouette analysis technique and get k = 208 as the one with best silhouette score so the divided my dataset into 208 clusters with K-means clustering.
Now I created a single sample data having random location, price, number of bedrooms, and bathrooms and predicted the cluster-number this sample belongs to and analyzed the data points of that cluster. My problem is that I also want to analyze the data points of the most similar cluster(s) to the single sample instance I created. How can we do this?

Comment: if anyone doesn't find this question making sense, plz let me know but don't downvote it because I really need help in this. thankyou

Comment: have you normalized the data? If you do this, without normalization then a measure like the price will contribute much more to your distance calculation in k-means clustering.

Comment: ya i have normalized the data as well

Comment: try sklearn.neighbors.NearestNeighbors and with 

model_knn = NearestNeighbors(metric = 'cosine', algorithm = 'auto')

model_knn.fit(X.to_numpy())

model_knn.kneighbors(y, n_neighbors = 10)

n_neighbors gives you most nearest points.